# Jenkinsfile Not able to push docker image

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm not able to push docker images into docker hub registry from jenkinsfile, i have created global credentials in jenkins with ID of dockerhub-id

```
stage('Push Docker Image') {
    container('docker') {
       withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerhub-id', passwordVariable: 'docker-hub-password', usernameVariable: 'docker-hub-username')]) {
       sh "docker login -u username -p ${dockerhub-id}"
       sh "docker push username/${image_name}:${image_tag}"
```

build log

```
Successfully tagged palani160385/frontend-app:master-e002b6bd
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag frontend-app frontend-app:master-e002b6bd
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Push Docker Image)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $docker-hub-username or $docker-hub-password
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dockerhub for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Comment: `dockerhub-id` is not a valid name for a Groovy variable. Try `dockerhub_id`. Currently, Groovy is trying to subtract two vars, one named `dockerhub` and another `id`. When it does not find `dockerhub` variable, it fails with `No such property: dockerhub`

Comment: thanks log Marat, it's working now